# C - Insertion Sort Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, insertion

I'm trying to sort a set of numbers like this:

```
A[]={3,6,7,2,9,1,2,7,2}
A[]={3,6,7,2,2,2,9,1,7}
```

So I've made this:

```
void sort_min(int* point, int size_array, int min_n){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while(point[i] != min_n){
        i++;
    }
    j = i+1;
    while(point[j] != min_n){
        j++;
    }
    k = j;
    for (j-1; j > i; j--){
        point[j] = point[j-1];
    }
    point[j] = min_n;
    j = k+1;
}
```

Like you can notice I've never used the `int size_array` cause *I don't know the way to match an iterative function like a* **`for`** *or a*  **`while`**  (That's the question. How to solve it?). I've done that, of course, but I've got a `Segmentation fault` like an answer.

The main concept is looking for a number `int min_n` and up to that point sort that number at each occurrence in the array.

Thanks for all.

Comment: What does it mean ?.  A[]={3,6,7,2,9,1,2,7,2}     
A[]={3,6,7,2,2,2,9,1,7}  . How second array is sorted ? or you just give two example . Make it clear .

Comment: You picked it wrongly , i think . Read some basic of it .

Comment: and what's `min_n` buddy? Plus your `for` loop isn't right... `for(j-1..)` it needs to be some kind of assignment statement.. like `j=j-1` or `j=size_arr` or something..

Comment: And as @Md.MokammalHossenFarnan has asked, what's the point of 2 arrays with the same name? or if you say the second is a sorted form of the first.. then how is it?

Comment: That's **basic**. I Know. But I'm trying to get a different answer. I mean, if have a **proof**  about  about the _better_ way to code it, could be great your answer. I'm trying to get a math way about an Algorithm... In the other hand, `int_min` is the number to look for. An array `A[]` is clear. An `int` array. I mean `int A[]={3,6,7,2,9,1,2,7,2}` ... and the other one is the same, but sorted in that way that I'm trying to get...

Comment: **and the other one is the same, but sorted in that way that I'm trying to get**. Its not sorted by any means.

Comment: I wanna sort **just one number**... In the main question an array `int A[]` is sorted by the 2 number in the first occurrence... But without loss of data...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need use `size_array` like below, if you are asking about this.

1. You need compare `i` and `j` with `size_array` in `while`.

   ```
   while (i < size_array && point[i] != min_n) {
         i++
   }
   ```
2. Need check value of `i`, `j` after `while`. They may be larger or equal to size_array.

   ```
   while (i < size_array && point[i] != min_n) {
         i++
   }

   // I guess when you don't find min_n, function can just return.
   if (i >= size_array)   
          return;

   j = i+1;
   while(j < size_array && point[j] != min_n){ // Also need check j's value.
          j++;
   }

   // Also guess when can't find the second min_n position, function can return.
   if (j >= size_array) 
          return; 

   k = j
   for (; j > i; j--)  // No need j-1.
          point[j] = point[j-1];

   // This is useless. When code come here, j == i and point[i] == min_n;
   point[j] = min_n;  

   j = k+1;
   ```

Comment: Yes. You got the main idea. But like you can notice, it works fine once. Like the example function in the question. But How would I match to order every `int min_n` number at first occurrence? That's the question.

Answer (score -2):

Try the Insertion Sort with the code as follows..

```
void sort_min(int point[], int size_array) 
{ 
   int i, key, j; 
   for (i = 1; i < size_array; i++) 
   { 
       key = point[i]; 
       j = i-1; 

       /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
          greater than key, to one position ahead 
          of their current position */
       while (j >= 0 && point[j] > key) 
       { 
           point[j+1] = point[j]; 
           j = j-1; 
       } 
       point[j+1] = key; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly reasonable insertion sort

Comment: Oh perfectly reasonable I see.. Please explain the for loop Mr @AndrewScott. What basic `c` programming teaches you that kind of looping? `for` **j-1**?

Comment: I wanna sort just one number... In the main question an array A[] is sorted by the 2 number in the first occurrence... But without loss of data...

Comment: Sorry @Karl, can you please explain a bit more on that? I didn't quite get that part,. So you're telling that the number `2` is sorted starting from **its** first occurrence.. and the rest is untouched... Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: "Rai Yes, you are right... I don't wanna move the main order in the array. Just _pushing_ the numbers to  sort another `int min_n` starting from its first occurrence. Look for, Moving and Sort... look for, moving and sort...